# Async await api call inside useEffect being called twice

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ept2I.png)

[image: network tab(duplicate api calls)]

When I click on the dropdown `button`, it'll trigger `API` calls and it works fine. However, if I click the dropdown `button` again (without refreshing the page), `API` calls(not the whole  `fetchData` function but only the await `cityAPIS` calls ) will call twice(ideally it should only be called once.)
Does anyone know why is this happening?
PS. I didn't use `React.strictMode`.

```
import CityApi from '@Api/CityApi';

export default function useFetchCityApi(
  initState,
  loadState,
  imgDispatch,
  selectCountry
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initState) {
      return;
    }
    async function fetchData() {
      imgDispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA', fetching: true });

      let data = await CityApi(
        loadState.load === 0 ? 0 : loadState.load - 30,
        selectCountry
      );

      if (data === 'error') {
        imgDispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA', fetching: true });
        return;
      }
      imgDispatch({ type: 'STACK_IMAGE', data });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [loadState.load]);
}
```

whole codebase:
[github codebase](https://github.com/0529bill)

Comment: Your `useEffect` call depends on `loadState.load`, thus when that state change, the callback is call again. You can add `if (loadState.load === 0) {...}` inside the callback.

Comment: As it seems you want to fetch cities when a country is selected, you should only be having `[selectCountry]` in `useEffect` dependency. And I think, you don't need `loadState.load === 0 ? 0 : loadState.load - 30` at all. You can just write `0` there. You can also remove `if (initState) { return; }` and instead, you can wrap whole code in effect under an `if ( ! isEmpty(selectCountry)) { ... fetch  }`. And (suggestion), It is better to name it as `selectedCountry`.

Comment: @AjeetShah one problem with putting selectedCountry as useEffect dependency is that if I click one city, then if I click on the same country again, useFetchCityApi wont triggered bc selectedCountry didn't change!
PS. thanks for the selectedCountry suggestion!

Comment: Hmm. You are right. There is issue when we select the same city. To fix it, you need to refactor lots of code.